# Adding lines in AWK?

Tags: gnu, gawk

Can you please help me? I need help coding the AWK, I can't get through this. Can also be a BASH solution.
Code:

```
1
4
7
5
5
1
4
8
3
6
```

My desired output is
Code:

```
1 5 .2
4 5 .8
7 12 .58
5 12 .41
5 6  .83
1 6  .16
4 12 .33
8 12 .66
3 9 .5
6 9  .5
```

As you can see I need to add the even and odd lines together to generate the second column. This value is kept for the 2 lines because I need to do some searching and add results up to get a percent.

After that I need to divide the value in the first column with the value of the same spot in the second column. to get the per cent.

I just can't get it done efficiently. What I'm doing right now is just getting the odd lines in a separate file from the even ones and then attaching the columns and proceeding to create an array for both files and then do the algebra. Must be a simple way with AWK that does not involve temporary files or anything like that.

Upon using dudiboy's advised piece of code on the following text file, these are the incorrect results I'm getting:

This is the list.txt file contents:

```
1
2
6
6
8
1
2
3
5


root@debian:/home/l0l/Documents/awk# awk 'a[NR]=$1; END {for (ln=2; ln<=NR; ln+=2){ print(a[ln], a[ln]+a[ln-1], a[ln]/a[ln-1]); print(a[ln], a[ln]+a[ln-1], a[ln-1]/a[ln]);}}' list.txt
1
2
6
6
8
1
2
3
5
2 3 2
2 3 0.5
6 12 1
6 12 1
1 9 0.125
1 9 8
3 5 1.5
3 5 0.666667
```

The percent's are way off and the way that it prints it out is way off as well, will keep trying however I'd really appreciate any help with this. Please guide me step by step about the advised command?

UPDATE:
    $ awk -v fmt="%-2i %-2i %.2f\n" 'NR%2{x=$1;next} {printf fmt,     x,x+$1,x/(x+$1); printf fmt,$1,x+$1,$1/(x+$1)}' file

Is the PERFECT solution !!!! THANKS A ZILLION!! so happy! However when I try to get the output of the command into a file I get a zero divide error

```
root@debian:/home/l0l/Documents/bash# awk -v fmt="%-2i %-2i %.2f\n" 'NR%2{x=$1;next} {printf fmt, x,x+$1,x/(x+$1); printf fmt,$1,x+$1,$1/(x+$1)}'     results >> RESULTS2.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=results FNR=648) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

I'm using it on a 2000 part list of numbers and there is sometimes 2 zeros in a  row so. so it produces the second column with also a 0 and then since we are dividing by zero we get this zero divide issue. How do we prevent this? I have to keep the 0's in the file, its super important. Maybe a different way to calculate percentage?
How to get a nice output without that zero divide?
For example if the list file is now:

```
0
0
1
5
5
6 
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

We get zero divides all over. Any insight of how to prevent this?

Comment: Did you try it with AWK? If you did and it failed, please add your code to your post and explain what issue is blocking you. This is the best way to get response on this site. Also check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's going on with the last 2 lines of your desired output? Why are there 4 columns?

Comment: Here's a start: `awk '{val1 = $1; getline; val2 = $1; ...}' file` -- add a couple of printf commands and that should be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -v fmt="%-2i %-2i %.2f\n" 'NR%2{x=$1;next} {printf fmt, x,x+$1,x/(x+$1); printf fmt,$1,x+$1,$1/(x+$1)}' file
1  5  0.20
4  5  0.80
7  12 0.58
5  12 0.42
5  6  0.83
1  6  0.17
4  12 0.33
8  12 0.67
3  9  0.33
6  9  0.67
```

#### Updated question with avoidance of division by zero

```
$ awk -v fmt="%-2i %-2i %.2f\n" 'NR%2{x=$1;next} {d=x+$1; printf fmt, x,d,(d?x/(x+$1):0); printf fmt,$1,d,(d?$1/(x+$1):0)}' file2
0  0  0.00
0  0  0.00
1  6  0.17
5  6  0.83
5  11 0.45
6  11 0.55
0  0  0.00
0  0  0.00
0  1  0.00
1  1  1.00
0  0  0.00
0  0  0.00
```

Comment: Updated because of zero divide issue

Comment: @user289944 See addition to answer for method to avoid division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple oneline awk example;

```
awk 'a[NR]=$1; END {for (ln=2; ln<=NR; ln+=2){ print(a[ln], a[ln]+a[ln-1], a[ln]/a[ln-1]); print(a[ln], a[ln]+a[ln-1], a[ln-1]/a[ln]);}}' list.1.txt
```

Hope this helps, the quest was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

for the desired output format

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {fmt="%d %d %.2g\n"} 
       NR%2  {v=$1; next} 
             {s=v+$1; printf fmt fmt, v,s,v/s,$1,s,$1/s}' file

1 5 0.2
4 5 0.8
7 12 0.58
5 12 0.42
5 6 0.83
1 6 0.17
4 12 0.33
8 12 0.67
3 9 0.33
6 9 0.67
```